# How to call a php function with parameters using Ajax and JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Trying to delete a record by using JQuery/Ajax function so that my page will not reload everytime I delete. I have a Movie.php that serves as a model object for Movie and this is where I put the function called delete_movie to delete based on movieId parameter. I have tried to call it inside my Jquery call but it looks like it is not calling my function delete_movie(movieId).

This is my Movie.php

```
<?php

class Movie {
    public static function delete_movie($movieId) {
        $db = Database::getDB();

        $query = 'DELETE FROM MOVIE
              WHERE movieId = :movieId';
        $statement = $db->prepare($query);
        $statement->bindValue(':movieId', $movieId);
        $statement->execute();
        $statement->closeCursor();
    }
}
?>
```

movielist.php

```
<tr class="delete_mem<?php echo $movie['movieId'];?>">
    <td><?php echo $movie['title']; ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $movie['releaseYear']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $movie['imdbId']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $movie['description']; ?></td>
    <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="<?php echo $movie['movieId'];?>">Delete</button></td>
</tr>
```

JQScript.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.btn-danger').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?")) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "model/Movie.php",
            data: {
                delete_movie : id
            },
            success: function() {
                alert('Success deletion!');
            }
        });
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

});

Comment: You can't; handle the POST data in `Movie.php`

Answer (score 1):

When PHP is running `movie.php`, it's just processing the class. The PHP within the file doesn't actually say to do anything.

If you don't need classes, you could just change your `movie.php` to

```
$db = Database::getDB();

$query = 'DELETE FROM MOVIE
      WHERE movieId = :movieId';
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->bindValue(':movieId', $movieId);
$statement->execute();
$statement->closeCursor();
```

If there's more in the file or you must use classes, then you need a controller that receives the url POST, and then calls `Movie::delete_movie($id)`.

You appear to be following the MVC pattern, the model and view you have, and adding this controller to control the actions, would be the final part.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call PHP code from JavaScript (not easily, at least). Fortunately for you, you *can* do what you're trying to achieve because you're sending a `POST` message to `Movie.php`. All that you have to do now is to handle that `POST` message in `Movie.php`.

```
<?php

class Movie {
    public static function delete_movie($movieId) {
        $db = Database::getDB();

        $query = 'DELETE FROM MOVIE
              WHERE movieId = :movieId';
        $statement = $db->prepare($query);
        $statement->bindValue(':movieId', $movieId);
        $statement->execute();
        $statement->closeCursor();
    }
}

// add this
if (isset($_POST["delete_movie"])) {
    Movie.delete_movie($_POST["delete_movie"]);
}
?>
```

I suggest you don't forget to add authentication. Otherwise, anyone can delete any movie from your database. Try adding a `session`. That's outside the scope of this question, though.